# How can I use flash[:notice] across domains?

Tags: session, heroku, sinatra

I have a website that is served via HTTP with a custom domain (e.g., mywebsite.com) on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

When a user wants to login, I redirect them to my Heroku application's non-custom URL via HTTPS (using [Piggyback SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#piggyback-ssl), because I am cheap and don't want to pay for [SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint)).

Then, after they've logged in, I redirect the user back to my custom domain since their traffic doesn't really need to be encrypted anymore.

Only problem is that before redirecting them, I display a message (e.g., "You've successfully logged in!") using `flash[:notice]` (with [sinatra-flash](http://rubysource.com/sinatra-flash/)). But I believe that since the user crosses from one domain to another in this process, though still on the same server, they don't see the message since their session data from domain X is not accessible from domain Y.

- Is my understanding of the problem correct?
- What is the right way to fix it?

---

**Update on 2012-10-12**:

So, the solution I ended up going with is a little hacky:

First, I added a new data model, `OneTimeFlash`, with a `token` field containing a random string for each record. Then I made it so that after the user logs in on domain X, I create a new `OneTimeFlash` instance and redirect to domain Y with the token in the query string:

```
# The model automatically generates a token before being created.
one_time_flash = OneTimeFlash.create(:message => "You've successfully logged in!")
redirect "#{DOMAIN_Y}/flash/#{one_time_flash.token}"
```

Then when the server detects this token in the request, it displays the flash:

```
get "/flash/:token" do |token|
  one_time_flash = OneTimeFlash.first(:token => token)
  flash[:notice] = one_time_flash.message unless one_time_flash.nil?
  one_time_flash.destroy
  redirect "/
end
```

(The ORM is [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), in case anyone's confused.)

Like I said: it's hacky, but it works. Can anyone think of any serious problems with this approach?

Comment: why saving things to the db just for a temp message to the user?

Comment: @RailsN00b: because I couldn't think of a better way! Can you?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use flash between domains in that situation since flash is only saved for the next request.

you could use HTML5 localstorage - [some random localstorage explanation](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2105-Exploring-HTML5-s-localStorage-Persistent-Client-Side-Key-Value-Pairs.htm) or [w3schools website on html5 localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)